# File I/O on iPad

Tags: ios, file, io

Experts.. a newb question

I have developed a GIS like app which runs perfectly within Xcode and iPad simulator environment.  Now I want to test on a real iPAD.  I have gone through the provisioning certificates process and able to run the app on my device.  The problem comes up when the program tries to read a file which is on my development computer (file path is something like /Users/user/Document/data.txt).

Can I copy that "data.txt" file to ipad and if I can, what will be it's path for I/O.

Thanks for your help.

KAS

Answer (score 1):

You will add it to your application. and it will be in the bundle.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"]];
```

After you load it up, Parse it with a string.

You can use NSScanner to parse your string

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *myData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:fileName encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding   error:&error];
NSScanner *myScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myData];
int myNewInt = 0;
if ([myScanner scanInt:&myNewInt])
{
    //Do Something with my New Int
}
```

Comment: OK that works..however I am using the old fashioned "fscanf()" to parse the data, what is the equivalent in here...  I guess I could convert it to a C string and then use sscanf() or is there a better way?

Comment: Is your file supposed to be in a specific format ? What are you using it for ?

Comment: Jason.. the file contains three fields in following format

12.34444 -34.45689 Label_for_point
.....

I read these field in x,y,lable using fscanf() function

Comment: Another option is to put the data in an xml file for NSDictionary and load it from the bundle. Then you will have the values in a Dictionary. Or even just an array.

Comment: OK.. you have lost me there :-).. can you explain that in code please

Comment: I did copy and paste and added a NSLog statement, but I am getting 0 for the values.  The numbers are float so I changed the code to 
float myNewNumber = 0.0;
if ([myScanner scanFloat"&myNewNumber])
NSLOG(@"%F\n", myNewNumber)
but I am getting zero in the log

Comment: Ok. I wrote up this example just now, and it worked. Perhaps your file is not being found ? Put in a breakpoint and hover over the items. See what is nil or 0x0

Answer (score 0):

You can include the file in your project then access it.  To get the full file path:

```
NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *filePath = [appFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.txt"];
```